# Oracle materialized views: 25/24 in REFRESH / NEXT parameter

Tags: oracle, refresh, materialized-views

I'm trying to figure out the meaning of `25/24` in this REFRESH parameter of an Oracle materialized view found on a repository:

`REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT trunc(SYSDATE) + 25/24`

I'm trying to find the correct refresh scheduling of this Oracle materialized view: 1/24 means "every one hour' but I'm not sure about the meaning of **25**/24 and I couldn't find the correct answer so far...

Can anyone give an help? Thanks in advance.

Marco

Comment: Why not just run `select trunc(sysdate) + (25/24) from dual` and see what you get? That would have taken less time than writing a question here.

Comment: @APC Its slightly more complicated than that as the OP is comparing `START WITH SYSDATE` (which is a variable time) to `NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 25/24` (which will always be 1am tomorrow).

Answer (score 1):

That's *tomorrow, 1 hour after midnight*:

```
SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         trunc(SYSDATE) + 25/24 what_is_that
  3  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           WHAT_IS_THAT
------------------- -------------------
06.12.2022 12:20:53 07.12.2022 01:00:00

SQL>
```

`trunc` "removes" time component from `sysdate` (sets it to midnight) and then adds 25 hours to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` documentation

> #### `NEXT` Clause
>
> Specify a datetime expression for calculating the interval between automatic refreshes.
>
> Both the `START WITH` and `NEXT` values must evaluate to a time in the future. If you omit the `START WITH` value, then the database determines the first automatic refresh time by evaluating the `NEXT` expression with respect to the creation time of the materialized view. If you specify a `START WITH` value but omit the `NEXT` value, then the database refreshes the materialized view only once. If you omit both the `START WITH` and `NEXT` values, or if you omit the `create_mv_refresh` entirely, then the database does not automatically refresh the materialized view.

Your statement:

```sql
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT trunc(SYSDATE) + 25/24
```

is effectively saying refresh every X hours where X is the difference between the time now (`SYSDATE + 0`) and the tomorrow at 01:00 (`TRUNC(SYSDATE)` gives midnight today and then `+25/24` adds 25 hours). Thus if you execute the `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` statement at exactly midnight then it will refresh every 25 hours, if you execute it at 9am then it would refresh ever 16 hours, etc.

If you wanted to run it every 25 hours then you can remove the `TRUNC`:

```sql
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 25/24
```

or, equivalently, using an `INTERVAL` literal rather than arithmetic:

```sql
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + INTERVAL '25' HOUR
```